# How do you create a binary-Decimal conversion program? (format provided)

Tags: python, binary, decimal

I was accidentally placed in a programming class rather than intro. to computers. Everything is completely over my head. Does anyone know how to do this?

I need to code a *decimal binary number conversion program* in Python (decimal number to binary and vice versa). The input to the program is a number and a base. The base can only be 2 or 10. If the base is 2, the input is a binary number and the output will be the corresponding decimal number, vice versa.

The program will first ask the user to input the base and then a number in that base. The base can only be “B”, “D” or S. “B”, “D” indicates the input is a binary number or decimal number, respectively and “S” stands for “Stop”. You need to check the validation of the input.

Output Format:

Your output should look as follows:

```
Please input the base(B:binary, d:deciam, S:Stop)
B
please input a number
1101
13
please input the base(b:binary, D:deciam, S:Stop)
D
Please input a number
13
1101
Please input the base(B:binary, D:deciam, S:Stop)
A
Your input in not a valid base
Please input the base(B:binary, D:deciam, S:Stop)
B
Please input is not a valid binary number
Please input the base(B:binary, D:deciam, S:Stop)
S
```

Comment: How can you accidentally be placed in a class? :) Shortest answer: switch course.

Answer (score 4):

dec to bin:

```
s = bin(n)[2:]
```

bin to dec:

```
n = int(s, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Function for Binary to decimal:

```
>>>def binary_to_decimal(binary):
       decimal=0
       for i in range(len(str(binary))):
           power=len(str(binary))-(i+1)
           decimal+=int(str(binary)[i])*(2**power)
       return decimal
```

Function for Decimal to binary:--

```
>>>def decimal_to_binary(arr,decimal):
       if decimal ==1:
           arr.append(1)
       else:
           rem = decimal%2
           arr.append(rem)
           rev = decimal/2
           decimal_to_binary(arr,rev)
       string=""
       for i in arr[::-1]:
           string+=str(i)
       return string
```

Main Function:--

```
>>>def function(changetype,number):
       if changetype =="D2B":
           result = decimal_to_binary([],number)
       if changetype=="B2D":
           result=binary_to_decimal(number)
       if changetype=="S":
           result="stop"
       return result
```

Output:-----

```
>>>function("D2B",18)
'10010'

>>>function("B2D",10011)
19

>>>function("S",any_parameter)
'stop'


-------------------Thanks------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fully functioning program that does most of what you want. Feel free to change it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    while True:
        base = input('Please input the base (B:inary, D:ecimal, S:top)\n')
        if base in {'B', 'b'}:
            convert = lambda b: str(int(b, 2))
        elif base in {'D', 'd'}:
            convert = lambda d: bin(int(d))[2:]
        elif base in {'S', 's'}:
            break
        else:
            print('Your input is not a valid base')
            continue
        number = input('Please input a number\n')
        try:
            print(convert(number))
        except ValueError:
            print('Your input is not a valid number')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```